# undefined reference to `gcry_check_version' , what's wrong?

Tags: build, makefile, cmake, centos

**cmake ..**

**make**

**then failed to build.**

**the error message is as follows:**

```
[ 96%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-color.o
[ 97%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-key.o
[ 97%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-main.o
[ 98%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-mouse.o
[ 99%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-term.o
[100%] Building C object src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/gui-curses-window.o
Linking C executable weechat-curses
../../core/libweechat_core.a(wee-network.o): In function `network_init':
wee-network.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `gcry_check_version'
wee-network.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `gcry_control'
wee-network.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `gcry_control'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/gui/curses/weechat-curses] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/gui/curses/CMakeFiles/weechat-curses.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

my os is centos 5.3, which package i should in stall in order to build this software successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to link an executable, missing libgcrypt library.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/

Comment: in fact i have installed that lib:(

Comment: how to tell cmake where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this. Since I'm using Code Blocks I found:

- Go to Settings> Compiler and Debugger
- Linker Settings
- Since the libraries are already installed --> Add the following Link Libraries:
- /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so
- /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so

This fixed the compiler errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.04, with libgcrypt.h installed in /usr/include (by the repository package), I only had to change the compiler settings. This should work with Ubuntu 14.04/14.10, and probably w/ other Debians.

I'm on Code::Blocks, so my instructions are for that. See [the documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Building-sources.html#Building-sources) for more information.

1. Go to Settings -> Compiler... -> Global compiler settings
2. On the "Compiler settings" tab, click "Other options", and AT THE TOP of that, put `'libgcrypt-config --cflags\'` (the `'` should actually be a backtick, but SO has odd formatting...)
3. On the "Linker settings" tab, under "Other linker options:", AT THE TOP put `'libgcrypt-config --libs\'` (again, with backticks instead of `'`).
4. Click OK and compile your project.